# i have 200 text file in hindi. want to remove white space the special character and find the find bigram and trigram in python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

```
import os

dir=os.getcwd()
print(dir)
dir1=os.path.join(dir,"test")
filename=os.listdir(dir1)
bad_chars = [';', ':', '!', "*","#","%"]
for i in filename:
    filepath=os.path.join(dir1,i)  #  the path
    file=open(filepath,"r",encoding="utf8") #open first text file
    read_=file.read()
    fields = read_.split(" ")
    print(fields)
    file1=open(filepath,"w",encoding="utf8")
    file2=open(filepath,"a",encoding="utf8")
    for j in range(len(fields)):        
        for p in bad_chars :
            fields[j].replace(i,' ')
            file2.write(fields[j])
            print ("Resultant list is : " , fields[j])
file.close()
file1.close()
file2.close()
```

I am trying to remove special character fro all the 200 text file

this is the code for bigram which I found

example my name is eshan.
output
my, name occurs 1
name,is  occurs 1
is, advance occurs 1
occurance can be more then 1 according to text

Comment: not clear what you are asking

Comment: Define functions. Import functions into one program

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat I want to remove all the special character from the all the text file and count the bigram of it

Comment: if I am not wrong the first code is written by yourself,there are too many loops and redundancy in their,which I think is not needed

Comment: You are repeating information, not clarifying it. The previous comment by Cricket_007 tells you exactly how to solve your problem; Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a free code writing service.

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat can you help me, what to do, to solve it

Comment: I think this is something you want, `for file in filename: with open(file,'w+') as f: for row in f: for bc in bad_chars:row.replace(bc,'  ')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
for file in filename:
    filepath=os.path.join(dir1,file)


    with open('inp.txt','r+') as f:
      texts = f.read()
      for c in bad_chars:
        texts=texts.replace(c,' ')

    #write to the file
    with open('inp.txt','w') as f:
      f.write(texts)
```